# Get wireless intefaces logical name

Tags: shell-script, awk

I try to get all the wireless interfaces that are available on a computer. For example if I use two network cards with logical name  `wlan0` and  `ra0`  respectively then I want to print them.

This is what I tried but I don't get any output:

```
sudo lshw -C network | awk 'if (/description: / $2 == "Wireless") {  /logical name: /{printf $3 "\n";}}'
```

I get syntax errors:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near if
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
```

Output without the `awk` part:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:96400000-96403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 02
       serial: 88:ae:1d:da:9e:99
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:92410000-92410fff memory:92400000-9240ffff memory:95400000-9541ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlp5s0b1
       serial: 00:26:82:e7:b8:32
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.4.0-53-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.0.14 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Update: If there is a better way to get what I want then I'd be happy to accept such answer.

Comment: can you edit the post and print the part of the result that contain Wireless without `awk`?

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F": " -v line=-1 '{if($2=="Wireless interface"){ line=NR+2}; if (line==NR){print $2}}' youfile
```

- `-F` set the separator
- `-v` pass a variable with value
- `NR` line number

I get the second item from the second line after i get `"Wireless interface"`

Comment: can you describe the code please??? I'm new to bash.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas is that work for you ?

Comment: good, if you have your answer please select it so it won't be unanswered

Comment: Oh right I forget it, excuse me.